# vertical align middle for dynamic size image within div

Tags: html, css

there is a method to vertical align middle an images within a div which is by using the line-height. But in my case my image within the div has dynamic sizes, so the line-height method doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/CM4Kx/

```
.company-logo-wrap {
width: 110px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 35px;
height: 110px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
position: absolute;
line-height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8zzv4/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the **position: absolute** and **line-height: 120px** and add **display: table-cell** and **vertical-align: middle**

```
.company-logo-wrap {
    width: 110px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    height: 110px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5WJ3z/